# Assigning serial number to duplicates in Google Sheet to order form responses per person

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have google form that can be filled by a person any number of times. I want to assign a serial number to each response coming from same email address, with the first response by that person (as per timestamp) marked as 1.

The "Response Number" Column should look like this. How can I do this using array formula so that it does not have be dragged down and applied.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In row 2 (under response number) try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)),))
```

and see if that works?

[image]